# How do I specify a specific VM Connector in a Mule FunctionalTestCase

Tags: mule

I am attempting to send a message to a VM endpoint using the FunctionalTestCase below:

```
@Test
public void CreateAddToCalendarOptionsApiTest() throws Exception{

    MuleClient client = new MuleClient(muleContext);
    String payload = "foo";
    Map<String, Object> properties = null;
    MuleMessage result = client.send("vm://processActivity",  payload, properties);
    assertEquals("foo Received", result.getPayloadAsString());

}
```

However, in the flow to be tested there are multiple VM connectors defined, so I am getting a TransportFactoryException stating:

```
org.mule.transport.service.TransportFactoryException: There are at least 
2 connectors matching protocol "vm", so the connector to use must be 
specified on the endpoint using the 'connector' property/attribute. 
Connectors in your configuration that support "vm" are: inMemoryVMQueue, 
recordDeletedActivityDLQStore, recordPublishedActivityDLQStore, 
recordUpdatedActivityDLQStore, deleteQueuedActivityDLQStore,  
(java.lang.IllegalStateException)
```

How do I specify that my client.send("vm://processActivity", payload, properties) uses a specific VMConnector?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use a query parameter:

```
client.send("vm://processActivity?connector=inMemoryVMQueue",  payload, properties);
```

... replacing `inMemoryVMQueue` by whatever connector you want to use.

It becomes functionally equivalent to an endpoint property.

Comment: That is an awesome nugget of information.  Thanks, David!  Do you know of any general documentation out there on constructing Mule URLs?

Comment: I found a good page on Mule URIs here:  http://www.mulesoft.org/documentation/display/current/Mule+Endpoint+URIs

Comment: It's really disappointing that Mulesoft keeps this kind of information hidden in their documentation. I would also expect to find tips like this in Mule books, but it looks like it's not the case :/

Comment: @GuidoN Take a look at section 12.2.1 of Mule in Action, second edition.

Comment: @David Dossot. Yep, as stressed already nowhere it's mentioned that the connector parameter is necessary. Which -besides- it's not intuitive, as the connector could be easily retrieved from the endpoint configuration. Shame : /

Comment: It is only necessary if you have more than one connector for a transport, as demonstrated in the raw JMS example of chapter 12: https://github.com/ddossot/mule-in-action-2e/blob/f449bf36f5897d96ff0729f4536efabaa7509005/chapter12/src/test/java/com/muleinaction/RawJmsMuleClientTest.java#L70-71

Answer (score 0):

"vm://test?connector=VM"  define like the below in your query path

`public void test() throws MuleException{
        MuleMessage message = new DefaultMuleMessage("ts",muleContext);
        MuleMessage reply = muleContext.getClient().send("vm://test?connector=VM", message);
    }`